# Have Arch Linux, want slack, must keep both; no cd, no usb or money; can chroot, pre-partitioned: GPT

Tags: linux, installation, arch-linux, slackware, chroot

I have a laptop with Arch Linux on it

```
[averagejoey2000@JoeyHobbyPCarchLinux arch-install-scripts]$ lsblk -l
NAME MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda    8:0    0 596.2G  0 disk 
sda1   8:1    0    25G  0 part /
sda2   8:2    0     2M  0 part 
sda3   8:3    0   512M  0 part /boot
sda4   8:4    0     4G  0 part [SWAP]
sda5   8:5    0     4G  0 part [SWAP]
sda6   8:6    0 266.3G  0 part /home
sda7   8:7    0 296.3G  0 part
```

I intend to install Slackware linux onto /dev/sda7 and up. I have no blank DVDs for an iso based installation, dd if=usbboot.img of=/dev/sdb gives me the boot menu, but my computer overheats before it progresses. on a separate laptop, instead of overheating, it waits for 3 hours, instead of the promised two minutes. I have neither the money nor the patience to order and wait for a mailed in dvd, purchased to experience the challenge of slackware. I want to be able to

```
mkdir /mnt/slack
mount /dev/sda7 /mnt/slack
(can't remember the command) proc proc proc/
slackinst
```

but I want to get to the part before the mounting, if it is even possible to do this sort of thing.

TL;DR: Have Arch Linux, want slack, must keep both; no cd, no usb or money; can chroot, pre-partitioned: GPT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use Grub2's ability to boot from an iso image, which you presumably already have, or may obtain. Assuming it is called *slack.iso*, (all commands as *sudo*)

```
 mkdir /boot/iso
 cp /path/to/your/slack.iso /boot/iso
```

Now edit the file */etc/grub.d/40_custom* and insert these lines:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 echo "Adding 40_custom." >&2
 exec tail -n +4 $0
 # This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
 # menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
 # the 'exec tail' line above.

 menuentry "Slackware ISO" {
    set isofile="/boot/iso/slack.iso"
    loopback loop (hd0,3)$isofile
    linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile noprompt noeject
    initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
 }
```

Now save, and update grub:

```
 update-grub
```

Reboot, choose the new entry, you shoudl see the live Slack boot.

If you now wish to install, you must remember that you cannot install to a disk in use, bt, since your live image has already been loaded into RAM, there is nothing to worry about: as sudo,

```
 umount -l /isodevice
```

and you are ready to start installing. Just make sure you choose the right (i.e. **empty**) partition to install to.

NB: if you are booting from efi, you will need to replace the *linux* line in 40_custom with:

```
  linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile noprompt noeject
```

NB2: at the cost of restating the obvious, I would also like to point out that, for the purpose of testing, by far the simplest thing to install a new OS is to do so inside a Virtual Machine. I cannot see the purpose of having two production machines on the same pc, since they cannot run concurrently. A VM instead can be run at the same time as the host OS, can share with it the whole disk, can be easily erased or relocated to a different pc, and so on.

Comment: the (hd0, 3) thing seems like grub legacy speak. Shouldn't it be sd[A-Z][0-9]?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, though I'm not certain if it work out for you. It might require some command line wizardry.

The first thing you need to do is mount the usbboot.img file:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/usbboot
$ sudo mount usbboot.img /tmp/usbboot
```

Then copy the initrd.img from it and unmount:

```
$ cp /tmp/usbboot/initrd.img /tmp/
$ sudo umount /tmp/usbboot
$ rmdir /tmp/usbboot
```

So now the initrd is in /tmp. But what is it?

```
$ cd /tmp
$ file initrd.img
initrd.img: gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: Fri Nov  1 01:07:44 2013, max compression
```

Ah, it's gzipped. Decompress it by renaming to .gz and decompressing:

```
$ mv initrd.img{,.gz}
$ gzip -d initrd.img.gz
```

Now what is it?

```
$ file initrd.img
initrd.img: ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC)
```

Now make a new directory for the slackware installer, and extract initrd using cpio (you need to be root for all the permissions to be right):

```
$ mkdir slackboot
$ cd slackboot
$ su
# cat ../initrd.img | cpio -i
```

**NOTE:** cpio will extract all its files to the current directory, so make sure you're inside the directory you want the files in when calling. It wouldn't try it from /.

You can chroot now and test it out:

```
# chroot .
# /usr/lib/setup/setup
Error opening terminal: xterm.
```

It seems you need a real tty/pty/whatever.
So log in to one of your real (non-X11) terminals as root (ctrl+alt+2).

```
# mount -o bind /dev /tmp/slackboot/dev
# mount -o bind /sys /tmp/slackboot/sys
# mount -o bind /proc /tmp/slackboot/proc
# chroot /tmp/slackboot
# /usr/lib/setup/setup
```

That will launch the installer, and should get you started. Don't blame me if you nuke your harddrive though.

Comment: You'll also need to make the main ISO available to the installer somehow (maybe copy the ISO into the slackboot directory and mount from inside chroot environment).